# TableForm in CreateDocument

Tags: list-manipulation, pdf-format, rasterize, document-creation

Writing:

```
list = {Magnify[
    Style["REAZIONI VINCOLARI ESTERNE:", FontSize -> 18, 
     FontFamily -> "Gill Sans", RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 0.7], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"\\\"h\\\"\", \"\\\"1e\\\"\"]\) = \
\!\(\*RowBox[{\"0\"}]\)"};

CreateDocument[{TextCell[Rasterize@TableForm@list, "Text"]}];
```

I get:

[image]

which is already a result, but unfortunately that is an image. Instead, writing:

```
list = {Magnify[
    Style["REAZIONI VINCOLARI ESTERNE:", FontSize -> 18, 
     FontFamily -> "Gill Sans", RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 0.7], 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"\\\"h\\\"\", \"\\\"1e\\\"\"]\) = \
\!\(\*RowBox[{\"0\"}]\)"};

CreateDocument[{TextCell[TableForm@list, "Text"]}];
```

I get:

[image]

which is definitely not as desired. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Is `CreateDocument[{TextCell["prova", "Text"]} ~Join~ Table[TextCell["ciao", "Text"], {3}]]` what you want?

Comment: Don't use `Print` for creating content, it is like `console.log` or something. Use `Table`, then `Join/Flatten` and friends if you need to reshape the list. There should be a good topic addressing this problem but it is though to find,.

Comment: `CreateDocument[ ExpressionCell[Column[{Style["test", Red], Subscript["h", "1e"]}],   "Output"] ]`?